# Jmeter Performance test - Error in % error column for positive test case

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am doing performance testing for web application using JMeter. I'm new in Jmeter, but went through the concepts, still not familiar with it. All test cases is good, except there is 100% on % error column. I still wondering why is it showing ? Even though I test it using real browser, it's working properly. But it show 100% error(after login to my web application and displays 0% error for Sign In and Sign Out option). Added View Results Tree, but it shows Response code 401 as there is no error when i do it in real browser. Please help me if anyone knows the solution. Many thanks....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some suggestions on how to fix this question up.  Your question should be minimal and verifiable.

Answer (score 0):

401 HTTP Response Code stands for [Unauthorized](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2). It means that you need to provide credentials somehow. JMeter provides [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to deal with different authentication types and it needs to be configured differently to bypass relevant authentication challenges.

The most straightforward and easy is Basic HTTP Authentication, it requires just username and password, see [Adding Auth](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-monitor-test-plan.html#adding_auth) chapter of [Building a Monitor Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-monitor-test-plan.html#building) guide for details.

If your application uses more complex authentication, like NTLM or Kerberos - you'll need to provide at least Domain and in case of Kerberos - supply realm and provide some extra settings in config files. See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for detailed instructions.